# Presenting SKStoreProductViewController re-activates inactive constraint

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, presentviewcontroller

I am presenting an SKStoreProductViewController, and getting some constraint conflicts. I can verify that a previously *de*-activated constraint is being re-activated. I can't see why this should happen.

See below, marked by `*** ———>`  `<———— ***` for your reading convenience.

The only possible gotcha I can think of is this: my app is landscape-only, so I have to subclass SKStoreProductViewController.shouldAutorotate to return false.

```
class MyProductViewController : SKStoreProductViewController {
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
}

func openStoreProduct(identifier: String) {
    let storeViewController = MyProductViewController()
    storeViewController.delegate = self

    let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier]
    storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: parameters) { [weak self] (loaded, error)  in
        if loaded {
            print("In: \(self?.myConstraint.isActive)")
            // *** ———> Prints "In: false". <——— ***

            self?.present(storeViewController, animated: true) {
        }
    }
}

func productViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
    print("Out: \(self.myConstraint.isActive)")
    // *** ———> prints "Out: true" <——— ***

    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It turns out that going to (or coming back from) the StoreViewController messes with quite a number of layout properties. This needs to be compensated for (i.e. hacked). In the above case, un-installing the constraint in IB fixed the problem. Will outline full solution when Answer Your Question becomes enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when returning from presenting the StoreProduct controller, some layout values have been restored to their IB values, losing values set programmatically, e.g. `isHidden`, `isActive`, etc.

In this case, I was replacing constraints in certain situations, but leaving the original IB one active when no change was needed. Upon return from the Store, the original constraints were *re*-activated, but their replacements were *also* still active. Of course they conflicted.

The solution is to un-check the constraint's "Installed" checkbox in IB, and replace (and activate) the constraint in code for *every* desired case. Rather than leaving it untouched when you don't want to change it.

For other UI things that may get messed up, you can set a flag in `productViewControllerDidFinish()` and test for it in your layout code.

This behavior *may* be related to the landscape issue mentioned in the question. On iPhone, the StoreProductViewController presents *only* in portrait mode. When the app is in landscape, and the current ViewController presents the StoreProduct one, the OS apparently *force-rotates* the app to portrait, before presenting the Store. You can see this happen briefly. (This is not an issue on iPad, because the Store presents as a popover, in either orientation.)

Comment: You're ahead of me on this one. — On the other hand, I get so many constraint conflicts in Apple's own built in view controllers that I hardly pay attention any more.